# Update method custom data source not called in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0, datasource

I am trying to update data using custom datasource. But when i call save after setting the id, it is calling the create method. I have also logged the $Model and in this the id is coming null. As id field is null, create method is called instead of update.

Below is the value of id when i log $Model in Model beforesave

```
[useTable] => applications
[id] => 191124
[data] => Array
        (
            [Application] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 191124
                    [Field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [@id] => 13312
                                    [@type] => 1
                                    [@value] => 10317
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

and when i log the $Model in create id field is null as

```
[useTable] => applications
[id] =>
[data] => Array
    (
        [Application] => Array
            (
                [id] => 191124
                [Field] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [@id] => 13312
                                [@type] => 1
                                [@value] => 10317
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

I am calling save using below code

```
 $data = array(
                    'id' => $archer_id,
                    'Field' => array(
                                            array(
                                                    '@id' => 13312,
                                                    '@type' => 1,
                                                    '@value' => 10317
                                            )
                                    )
                            );

$this->Application->id = $archer_id;
$this->Application->save($data,false);
```

Model which i am using is

```
class Application extends ArcherAppModel {

public $hasMany = array('Archer.Assessment');

public $_schema = array(
    'Field' => array('type' => 'array')
);

public function beforeSave( $options = array() ) {
    $this->log(array("message" => "Data in application before save ","data" => $this->data),'debug');
    return true;
} 
}
```

Read function in datasource code is

```
public function read ( Model &$Model, $queryData = array(), $recursive = null ) {
    $this->Model = $Model;
    try {
        $mid = $this->get_module_id();
        $key = $Model->alias . ".id";
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $queryData['conditions'] ) ) $rid = $queryData['conditions'][$key];
        elseif ( $Model->id ) $rid = $Model->id;
        else $params = $queryData['conditions'];

        $params = $this->_params(array(
            "moduleId" => $mid, 
            "contentId"=>$rid
        ));
        $results = $this->_getSoap('records')->__soapCall('GetRecordById', array('GetRecordById' => $params));
        if ( property_exists( $results, 'GetRecordByIdResult' ) ) return Xml::build($results->GetRecordByIdResult);
        return array();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {

        $this->log("OH No...");
        $this->log($e->getMessage());
        return array();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an id does not automatically mean it will be an update. Consider the case of saving with mysql where the primary key field is *not* autoincrement - This (extremely common) case is also supported by the model layer of CakePHP, where inserting and updating with a fixed primary key value both work.

The way the save method works is to [check if the id exists](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.5/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1818), and if it does not the save method [clears the model id](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.5/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1904-L1906):

```
if (!$exists && $count > 0) {
    $this->id = false;
}
```

The consequence of that being [an insert, not an update](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.5/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1914-L1938).

```
if (!empty($this->id)) {
    ... update ...
} else {
    ... insert ...
}
```

The custom datasource mentioned in the question is not shown, but it would appear it does not implement "does this id exist?". That or the model's exists method ([which is just a count, if it issues a query to the datasource](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.5/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L2884-L2914)) is returning false for a different reason.

### Forcing an update

To determine yourself whether it is an insert of update, either check why the find-by-primary-key call in `Model::exists` doesn't work and fix the datasource, or override `ModelName::exists` to implement whatever logic is necessary i.e.:

```
// Application Model
public function exists($id = null) {
    if (should be an update) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```